# Objects in ExtJS. Ext.create or new operator?

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJS. I started to program a little form. And I got completely confused about the use of Ext.create and the new operator.

So here is the code:

I wanted to program a form. I found a small example on one of the sencha pages. It creates a form like this:

```
var descAndSystem = new Ext.form.Panel ({
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'vbox',
    margins: '5 5 5 5',
    xtype: 'form',
    title: 'Some title',
    id: 'descAndSystem',
    width: '800', 
    items: [
       { xtype: 'textarea',
     fieldLabel: 'Provide a description',
     name: 'rightdescription',
       },
       {
      xtype: 'combobox',
      fieldLabel: 'Choose System',
      store: systems,
      queryMode: 'local',
      displayField: 'name',
      valueField: 'name',
      name: 'system'
       }
    ]
});
```

then I used descAndSystem as component in a viewport:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    id: 'wizardcontainer',
    items: [
        descAndSystem,
        {
            region: 'south', 
            layout: 'hbox',
            margins: '5 5 5 5',
            items: [
               { xtype: 'button', text: '&lt;&lt; Back', handler: onNext },
               { xtype: 'button', text: 'Next &gt;&gt;', handler: onNext },
               { xtype: 'button', text: 'Cancel', align: 'right', handler: function () { alert ('Abgebrochen geklickt.'); } }
            ]
        }
   ]
});
```

After a lot of trial and error I found that I can access the values of my form by the following code:

```
Ext.getCmp ('descAndSystem').getForm ().findField ('rightdescription').getValue ()
```

in contrast to what one of the books I bought said the following code did NOT work:

```
Ext.getCmp ('rightdescription').getValue ()
```

But my real problem is that I would expect that

```
Ext.create ('Ext.form.Panel', { .... });
```

is the same as

```
new Ext.form.Panel ( {...});
```

But when I do the latter the Chrome interpreter says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Panel' of undefined'
```

Again, after a lot of trial and error, the following worked:

```
new Ext.Panel ( {...});
```

Not only that I couldn't find any reference to an object of that name in the documentation, also the line

```
Ext.getCmp ('descAndSystem').getForm ().findField ('rightdescription').getValue ()
```

now yields an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getForm'
```

In addition, I was trying to replace descAndSystem by another form by DOM manipulation, there are various replace methods in the documentation. None of them worked, I always got the error message "has no method 'replace'".
I have the strong suspicion that I got something wrong fundamentally. Any hints? I am using ExtJS 4 and Chromium 17.0.963.56 on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong.  Ext.create('className', {}) would produce the same result as new className({}).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The major difference is that `Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel')` will automatically download the appropriate javascript file if the `Ext.form.Panel` class does not exist.  The vanilla `new` operator can not do this - it has no idea what a `Ext.form.Panel` might be or where the definition might be found.

The *Cannot read property 'Panel' of undefined'* error indicates that not only is `Ext.form.Panel` not defined, neither is the parent `Ext.form` namespace object.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
name: 'rightdescription',
```

to

```
id: 'rightdescription',
```

and you can access your textarea directly using the:

```
var yourTextArea = Ext.getCmp ('rightdescription');
var yourTextAreaContent = yourTextArea.getValue();
```

Comment: More like 'add the line'. Removing `name` from form field is hardly a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var descAndSystem = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {...})
```

Here is the documentation for `Ext.create()` http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-create

As for your other issues...

1. When you say `new Ext.Panel({...})` you are no longer creating a form panel so the `getForm()` method will not be available.
2. As @NTom showed, give any component an `id` and you will be able to access it using `Ext.getCmp`. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp

Comment: You probably misspelled `Ext.Panel`, but - what are you creating when you say `new Ext.from.Panel({...})` then?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I copied the example from he sencha page:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-ext-js-4

the index.html includes ext-debug.js. When I include ext-all-debug.js, then the new operator starts working :-)

Thanks for your help.
Greets
Kai