# ExtJS using "new objectname();" vs "Ext.create(...);" --> equal?

Tags: extjs

ExtJS Library using now.
I have a one question.

```
myClass = {
    myText: Ext.define("myedit", {
        extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text'
    })
};

var A = new myClass.myText();
var B = Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text");
```

A & B is same? 
I want know problem when using like A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objects in ExtJS. Ext.create or new operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481828/objects-in-extjs-ext-create-or-new-operator)

Answer (score 1):

This has been covered in a fairly [large amount of detail](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127671-Ext.create-vs-the-keyword-new) in the Sencha forums, the short of it is, try to use the create method wherever possible, for by far the majority of cases it will be the recommended course of action.